# Flash actionscript 3 addFrameScript not working properly

Tags: actionscript-3, movieclip

I have a movie clip being loaded and frame script being added to the movie's timeline dynamically.  The frame scripts seem to work some of the time but other times it seems to skip entire key frames that contain the dynamically added frame script.  Was just wondering if `MovieClip.addFramScript()` is just unreliable or if anyone else has every come across issues like this.

Comment: I wouldn't call it unreliable, please post your code as the problem probably lies in how your trying to accomplish this.

Comment: Are you trying to call addFrameScript() on a movie clip created in Flash Pro? Flash Pro will generate calls to addFrameScript() in the constructor. These could end up overriding your own handlers.

Answer (score 1):

try this code,

on timeline

```
//Movieclip instance name 'MC'

MC.addFrameScript(0 ,stopframe);

function stopframe():*
{
    MC.stop();
}
```

or Class file (and using label names)

```
package
{
    import flash.display.MovieClip;
    import flash.display.FrameLabel;
    import flash.display.*;

    public class MC extends MovieClip
    {
        private var labels:Object

        public function MC()
        {
            labels = this.currentLabels;

            for ( var i:int = 0; i < labels.length; i++ )
            {
                var framelabel:FrameLabel = labels[i];
                labels[ framelabel.name ] = framelabel.frame
            }

            addFrameScript( labels["animstart"], animStart, labels["animend"] - 1, animEnd );
        }

        public function animStart():void
        {
            trace("animation start");
        }

        public function animEnd():void
        {
            trace("animation end");
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Its not unreliable in my experience.  However syntax is very key, flash will not throw an error for this type of syntax issue.

Snippet:

```
addFrameScript((totalFrames-1),fn_frame); //Correct

addFrameScript((totalFrames-1),fn_frame()); //Incorrect, it will run right away and not on the last frame (the difference is the extra brackets)


public function fn_frame():void
    {
        trace("END");

        }
```